# How well is SQL Server implemented in PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm getting a new project some time now and wanted to use PHP for this one, as I don't have the time to get started with MVC and absolutely hate C# for Webdev.

So I was thinking of going "back to my roots" and use PHP and PDO for that. Problem is, the Databases are all SQL Server 2003 and I don't quite know how well that is covered in PDO.

Does anybody have experience with this or should I go on getting ASP.NET-MVC into my head (Which I will do anyways, but this project needs fast deployment...)

Comment: there is no such thing as "SQL Server 2003" - there's SQL Server 2000, and SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 - no 2003 version, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common problem when using PHP and MSSQL is using an old (faulty) driver. Also, have a read of the comments on the PHP [MSSQL manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that PDO supports MS SQL, however I have successfully used the [ADODB abstraction layer](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) against both MS SQL 2000 and 2008 without issues.  Your mileage may vary...